# Is it possible to dynamically refresh a calculated field on the Edit form when a connected field is changed?

Tags: infopath, calculated-column, conditional

On the Edit form, I am trying to dynamically have a calculated field show updated values when the connected field is changed. The idea is to give the user more details on the selected week. Is this possible?

I am using InfoPath to show calculated fields on the Edit form.

For example, I want to change from week 45 and want it to display the extra details in the calculated field. As you can see below:
[image: info path edit]

However, it does not change once the relevant or connected field is changed from 45 to 46:
[image]

Is there a way to have this done? I appreciate any help.

Edit: I am considering using PowerApps to modify the form, however, I still have no clue where to go to make the same request work on it. Researching...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible with infopath but you need to use text field and make the calculations using info-path functions. The build in calculated field will recalculate only when you submit the form. With normal text field you can use info-path function to make the calculation. Right click on the field and click on text box properties. Then next to the Default value click on the fx button. The you can insert the value of another filed (or use it in specific function to come up with your calculated value)